# cookieless load test with webtest

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, load-testing, coded-ui-tests

The problem: Load test does not create new instances of `WebTest`,
which makes each new request preserve the cookies

I've recorded a coded web test which has a structure of:

```
public class SomeWebTest : WebTest
{
    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()  
    {
        // need to cleans cookies here, otherwise already logged in
        yield return LoadLoginFormPageRequest;
        yield return PostLoginData;
        yield return PostLoginPageRequest;
    }
}
```

Put it inside a `loadtest` with constant load of 20 users.
After one thread is finishing with all 3 requests, same instance is being reused in another thread and all the cookies are preserved, thus the next thread thinks the visitor is already authorized.

How shall I clean the cookies or restructure my load test to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to set all the cookies to expired for each of the rquests at the end of a single test as so:

```
    yield return ..
    yield return ..
    yield return ..

    foreach (Cookie cookie in LoadLoginFormPageRequest.Cookies)
                cookie.Expired = true;

    foreach (Cookie cookie in PostLoginData.Cookies)
        cookie.Expired = true;

    foreach (Cookie cookie in PostLoginPageRequest.Cookies)
        cookie.Expired = true;
```